# SSRS Default parameters not showing up when the report is loaded

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Overview: I have 4 report parameter: Start Date, End Date, Phone Number and Skill.  Phone number has a default 7 rows as default values and skill has 147 rows as default values.

Issue: When I preview my report I can see that the Phone number is auto-populated by the default value that I set, but the Skill parameter is blank even though i set it up to have a default value based on a sql query. so now i am having issues setting up a data driven subscription.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your available values are coming from a query as well, does entering the default skill as a hardcoded value work?

Comment: Does your skill parameter also have "available values"? By "blank" do you mean default values are not selected, or that the parameter has no values at all?

Comment: Are you experiencing the issue in BIDS and/or are in the report server? In BIDS, have you tried to delete the report cache? In the report server, have you checked the parameters default values (`Manage` => `Parameters`)?

Comment: The drop down parameters are multivalue and has a default value. What i discovered is that if the skill will auto selected based on the phone number then the skill default values appeared when selecting a phone number and when the report loadsnit autonatically populate the skill default values